# Custom Op in Tensorflow C

Tags: c++, c, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a TF custom op using Tensorflow C API. I've already read the [Adding a New Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op) and [Install TensorFlow for C](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) but there is almost no tutorial for creating a custom op using Tensorflow C. So, I was wondering if somebody can show me a small example code for it?

I cannot use the bazel build system in my environment, so I assume I cannot use Tensorflow C++ API, since I only have to use a static or shared library for the custom op code. Please let me know if this task is still possible in Tensorflow C++ API.

Comment: @Fureeish since TF is written is C++, I thought maybe there is still a workaround in C++ for not using bazel for this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question: This task is possible in TensorFlow C++ API, but to build TensorFlow C++ API you do need bazel.